# broken pipe when executing bash in python

Tags: python, bash

everyone, I encouter the error of Broken pipe when trying to executing bash in python.

Here is my bash file, run.sh

```
INPUT=`python -c "print 'uid='+'A'*0x4"`
TEST=$INPUT
LEN=$(echo -n "$INPUT" | wc -c)
cp $(which qemu-mipsel-static) ./qemu
echo "$INPUT" | chroot . ./qemu -E CONTENT_LENGTH=$LEN -E CONTENT_TYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -E REQUEST_METHOD="POST" -E HTTP_COOKIE=$TEST -E REQUEST_URI="/authentication.cgi" -E REMOTE_ADDR="192.168.1.1" htdocs/web/authentication.cgi 2>/dev/null
echo 'run ok'
rm -f ./qemu
```

Here is how I tried to call execute the bash in python:

```
bash_file_path =run.sh
op = commands.getstatusoutput("bash %s" % (bash_file_path) )    
print op[1]
```

However, I encouter the error in the line 5 of the run.sh:

run.sh: line 5: echo: write error: Broken pipe

I also tried the subprocess, however, got the same errors:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["bash", bash_file_path], shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE )
print p.stdout.readlines()
print p.stderr.readlines()
```

the results:

```
[]
[run.sh: line 5: echo: write error: Broken pipe]
```

Comment: Does the Bash script work on the command line? Does `qemu` read all of the input? What sort of amounts of input are you passing in?

Comment: "Broken pipe" means standard input (or something) was closed while something was still trying to write.  It's pretty common in scenarios where the recipient hangs up somewhere in the middle of a stream of input, typically when it has read enough to complete its task, but also e.g. if it encounters an error and terminates without processing its input at all.

Comment: Does the script execute with the required permissions to run `chroot`?

Comment: You are trimming the newline when calculating LEN  but not trimming it when you are actually submitting the input. Is this a bug? (I don't think a single byte will cause the broken pipe error as such.)

Comment: On pure aesthetics, I would do almost all of this in the calling Python script, and just call `chroot ./qemu` as a subprocess.

Comment: @tripleee The bash script can work on the command line. Yes, for now the `qemu` read all of the input.  the amouts of the input may be very large, like 'A'*0xffffff

Comment: For the third question. Yes, we have the permissions. The script should be actually `op = commands.getstatusoutput("echo mypass | sudo -S bash %s" % (bash_file_path) )    
`. So the permissions are granted.

Comment: For the fourth question. I don't understand. On the command line, the bash script is ok.

Comment: Finally, actually, `chroot . ./qemu` is used to execute the program `htdocs/web/authentication.cgi` which is a `MIPS` binary. And I want to put all of the content in `$INPUT` as a input to the `htdocs/web/authentication.cgi`.

Comment: Can you give some hints about the probem is from the long `$INPUT` or the latter parameters to the `qemu`?

Comment: What happens if you calculate the length correctly? If you `echo "$INPUT" | wc -c` to calculate the length (remove the `-n`) or conversely add the `-n` where you pass it to `qemu` does it magically start to work?

Comment: The "broken pipe" will not happen for very short inputs because the OS only notices when an I/O buffer fills up.

Comment: Thanks, however, `echo "$INPUT" | wc -c` still can not work. For now, I have to still run the bash on the command line. :(.  I wonder whether there are any tricks to  expand the IO buffer.   On the other hand, it is wired that if I run the bash on the command line, the system will not check the buffer size, but will check it in the python environment.